# <select> accessing values with $_POST

Tags: php

I am little confused about this because everywhere I look for it, they have it same as me, but I have problem that I am listing various of options by `<select>` and `<option>` and I need to get back the value of what I have clicked, by it doesn't seem to be working, so if there is someone who knows?

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "uklidy");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM budovy ORDER BY id ASC";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
echo '<select name="budova_name">
';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["jmeno"].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

$budova = $_POST["budova_name"];
echo $budova;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit it with a form.

```
<?php

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "uklidy");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM budovy ORDER BY id ASC";  
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); 
    echo '<form method="post" action="mypage.php">';
    echo '<select name="budova_name">';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["jmeno"].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<input type="submit">';
    echo '</form>';
```

and if you're talking about getting the selected value on the same page you're gonna have to use javascript for that. PHP is a server side language.

Comment: And if i do? Can you even help me with that?